# Galois Groups and intermediate field extensions

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I'm stuck in the structure of Galois group of a field extension over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have the polynomial $fg=(x^{6}-4)(x^{4}-3)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Is easy to find that the extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ given by this polynomial is $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i,\sqrt[4]{3})$. So $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=24$; as this extension is normal and separable we have that $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=|G=Gal(E:\mathbb{Q})|=24$.

Justify that exist 3 intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $E$ is not hard (because by Sylow's Theorem if $s_{2}=1$ then exists $H\triangleleft G$, and so $E^{H}|\mathbb{Q}$ is normal of degree 3, but the only subextension with this property is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}:\mathbb{Q})$ that is not normal.)

Justify that exists only one $3$-Sylow subgroup and determinate the fixed field $E^{H}$ is where the problems start to me. I know that by Sylow's Theorem $s_{3}$ (where this is the 3-Sylow subgroups of G) should be 1 or 4. I don't know how to discriminate $s_{3}=4$, because I don't know what this implies (all that comes to my mind is that there are only one extension of order 8, $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{3})$. I'm not sure if this reasoning is correct.)

And the last thing that I don't know: justify the existence of a normal subgroup $K\subset G$ so $E^{K}=E_{f}\cap E_{g}$ and that $G/K$ is abelian. What comes to my mind is that this is related to the structure of $G$ (it can be written as the direct product of two subgroups).

My try: $E_{f}\cap E_{g}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}i)$. So I have to find one $K$ that $E^{K}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}i)$ and that $G/K$ is abelian.

Any hint to continue is appreciated.

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @rae306 I know. But if you write down who is the 3rd root of the unity you got $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, then, what you have for $E_{fg}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i,\sqrt{3}i,\sqrt[3]{2})$ so by making operations what you have is what I said (look that $\sqrt{3}=(\sqrt[4]{3})^{2}$.

Comment: You are right, I judged too fast ;) That's why I deleted my comment. Where does this problem come from? It looks interesting.

Comment: @rae306 Is an exercise of one course of Galois Theory that I've had in my university. We've solved one that is similar, but this is the one where I'm stuck, because of little changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For justifying the existence of a unique Sylow-$3$ subgroup, note that such a subgroup is unique if and only if it is normal, and a normal Sylow-$3$ subgroup would correspond to a Galois subextension $ K/\mathbf Q $ with degree $ 8 $. You already know a degree $ 8 $ subextension of $ E/\mathbf Q $, namely $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{3}, i)/\mathbf Q  $, so all you need to show is that this subextension is Galois. This trivially follows from it being the splitting field of $ X^4 - 3 $.

For the last problem, you know that $ [E_f : \mathbf Q] = 6 $ and $ [E_g : \mathbf Q] = 8 $, and yet their compositum has degree $ 24 $. This means $ [E_f \cap E_g : \mathbf Q] = 2 $, and in fact armed with this result you can determine $ E_f \cap E_g = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3}) $. The subgroup $ K \subset G $ corresponding to this subfield has all of the required properties.

Since the extensions $ E_f $ and $ E_g $ become linearly disjoint over $ E_f \cap E_g $, you can in fact see from this result that there is a short exact sequence

$$ 0 \to C_3 \times C_2 \times C_2 \to G \to C_2 \to 0 $$

Comment: I don't have studied yet the last thing you've commented... Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @sopach96 All it means is $ G $ has a normal subgroup $ N $ such that $ N \cong C_3 \times C_2 \times C_2 $ and $ G/N \cong C_2 $.

Answer (score 1):

Your first justification is fine.

For the second one we in fact have $E_f \cap E_g = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. Now $E / \mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a Galois extension with $\lvert \text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})) \rvert = [E : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}) ] = 12$ and so $K:=\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})) \leq G$ is a subgroup of index $2$ and hence it is normal in $G$. The quotient $G/K$ has order $2$, so it is abelian.

However, this does not mean that $G$ is a direct product of $K$ and $G/K$. For example, the dihedral group $D_{6}$ has a subgroup $H =\{1, r, r^2\}$, but is not a direct product of $H$ and $D_6/H$ - it is not even abelian.

Comment: Thank you @DavidPopovic

Comment: Thank you @DavidPopovic Only two comments. The first, in $K\leq G$ you would like to write $K<G$, don't you? And the second, what do you want to explain to me in your last paragraph?

Comment: I use $\leq$ for the subgroup, but of course $K$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. The last paragraph is about the following: you have written in your question that "this is related to the structure of G (it can be written as the direct product of two subgroups)". Which two subgroups do you mean? I don't think this is true.

Comment: I didn't know that we can use $\leq$ for subgroups too... Sorry... And what I said about the structure is that as let be $K$ and $H$ two subgroups of order $2^{3}$ and $3$ respectively, and as $H\cap K={1}$ we know that $H\times K\simeq HK$ and as $|G|=|K||H|$, we have that $G\simeq H\times K$. The only thing we have to prove is that exists one normal subgroup of $G$ of order $2^{3}$ (because of order 3 we got it). I haven't prooved it, is only my intuition... Maybe I'm wrong... @DavidPopovic

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood which groups you meant :) (I thought you were saying that $G$ is a direct product of $K$ (the group you were looking for) and another subgroup.)